# How to obtain data from website that does not provide an API? Swift

Tags: html, swift

I am working on a iOS app, where I need to retrieve information, more specifically "Schedule information". This website does not provide an API. I am not sure how to approach this, and would like recommendations or guidance on how to do this. I've looked at parsing HTML, but I am not sure if that's the best way to do it, or even know where to start with it.

Are there any special ways to do this ?

Comment: If there is no API then parsing HTML is the only way to do it.

Comment: Here is a html parsing php library http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needless to say, you should check out the site's terms of service. Many of them explicitly have ToS that forbids that practice. Personally, I'd suggest contacting the web site in question and see if they have a published API, and if so, use that. It's going to be much easier and more robust than trying to write code that parses the HTML from the site. And even if they don't have a published API, you can engage them in the conversations regarding how they'd recommend you interface with them.

But, in answer to your question, google HTML parsers, such as [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) or [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple). Even though it's written in Objective-C, I personally prefer TFHpple, even from Swift. For introduction how to use it, see http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios. That shows how to use it from Objective-C, but the process is similar in Swift.

The process is basically:

1. Copy the six TFHpple `.m` and `.h` files to your your project.
2. When prompted to create the bridging header, do so, and then add the following line to that bridging header file:

   ```
   #import "TFHpple.h"
   ```
3. As described in that tutorial, make sure to add `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml` to your "Header Search Paths". Also add the `libxml2` library to your list of libraries to include in the "Build Phases" of your target settings.

But at that point, the process is much like what's described in that Wenderlich tutorial. For example, if I want a list of the question titles on the first page of the Stack Overflow site, you could do:

```
func retrieveAndParse() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        let hpple = TFHpple(HTMLData: data!)
        let xpathSearchString = "//div[@class='summary']/h3/a"
        if let nodes = hpple.searchWithXPathQuery(xpathSearchString) as? [TFHppleElement] {
            for node in nodes {
                print("content = '\(node.firstChild.content)'")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer ! I will do my best to learn this parsing stuff... now I have a guide to start. I have never worked with Objective-C, so this will be a challenge for me. I would up vote your answer, but someone gave me a negative rate on my question and lowered me from 15 to 13 and now I can't up vote answers. :(

Comment: Regarding Objective-C vs Swift, that's why I provided Swift example in my answer, so you can see how simple the translation is. Plus, I'd suggest on focusing on the big-picture, conceptual stuff in that tutorial. The main thing is to get your arms around the xpath query stuff (which is the same in Swift and Objective-C).

Comment: Frankly, the TFHpple API isn't the complicated thing here. The real PITA is going to be looking at HTML in your web browser (either "view source" or load it into your HTML editor of choice), figuring out what the xpath query should look like, try it, and when it doesn't work, go back to HTML figure out what went wrong, and then repeat. (Whenever I've done this, it's always taken a good deal of trial-and-error to get it just right.) And if the site does any authentication, it gets even messier very quickly.

Comment: Rob, thanks once again. I will follow the tutorial.. if any other question arise, mind if I tag you ?

Comment: If you ask a question on Stack Overflow and you don't receive any response at all after a few days, then feel free to bring it to my attention. But I don't want to be your first line of inquiry (I get too many questions sent directly to me): Only reach out if you've posted question online and you've received no meaningful answers after a few days. Besides, if you post on Stack Overflow, there's a good chance I'll see it anyway. lol.

Comment: Ok thank you !! So don't want to be my mentor ? LOL.. I appreciate your help anyways. I will work on this.